# Permission Set Recalculation Failed

Tags: permission-sets, permission-set-groups

I am attempting to recalculate a permission set, but I am getting the following error. I can't figure out which Permission in the Permission Sets in the group is failing?

> Permission set group calculation failed : Can't save permission set
> ___, which is assigned via permission set group to a user with user license Salesforce. The user license doesn't allow the permission:
> Edit Order Events

Comment: This might be related to [KI](https://trailblazer.salesforce.com/issues_view?id=a1p4V000002LNPZQA4&_ga=2.23860156.703348375.1662197365-261753318.1620926533), Can you try workaround mentioned?

Comment: in the org, in Order Settings, is Order Events enabled?

Comment: @cropredy - It is not.